# Как создать окно в qt, которое будет работать пока выполняется длительная операция

Tags: c++, qt, ui

Мне нужно создать окно, которое будет показывать прогресс долго выполняющейся функции. В самой функции используются потоки, так что я не могу запускать эту функцию в отдельном потоке, иначе она сильно замедляется. Так же не хочется включать файл с функцией к qt, то есть чтобы этот файл был независимым от интерфейса. Единственное что я нашел это QCoreApplication::processEvents() , но тогда придется подключать файл к qt. Есть ли какое-нибудь решение?

Comment: других решений нет: или отдельный поток, или вызовы к `processEvents()`... Правда не понятно, чем отдельный поток может замедлить выполнение...

Comment: да, можно ещё передавать независимый callback в свою функцию и уже из него вызывать `processEvent()`, если цель только в том, чтобы уменьшить связность...

Answer (score 4):

Для отображения прогресса операции чаще всего используется [QProgressDialog](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.8/qprogressdialog.html), автоматизирующий отображение в зависимости от текущих данных прогресса.

Без создания дополнительного потока не обойтись, в Qt GUI исполняется в одном потоке. Общение между объектами прозрачно организуется через сигналы-слоты, между объектами в разных потоках содержимое сигнала преобразуется в сообщение.
Вам так или иначе писать обертку над вашим функционалом и помещать объект, реализующий функционал, в поток через [moveToThread](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.8/qobject.html#moveToThread), создав для этого отдельный от GUI поток.